# Sum values into buckets/bins specified by a tensor of the same shape in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am looking for an efficient method to sum floating-point variables into buckets specified by another tensor.

I specify efficient because the actual inputs and outputs are rather big. They fit into memory without an issue (millions of elements), but if we square the memory or computation complexity from what's necessary, we would run into problems.

Also, C-like solution that just loops over inputs and adds to array/hashmap is theoretically efficient, but results in terrible execution time in TF, I am seeking something that properly leverages multiprocessing. This requirement would usually boil down to not having non-parallelized loops over single array elements.

Example of the problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

buckets = 8
indices = tf.convert_to_tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5], tf.int32)
values = tf.convert_to_tensor([.5, .3, .2, .1, 1., 1., 1., .1], tf.float32)

# Inefficient solution that adds a new dimension,
# materializes a dense tensor, and then sums along the added dimension
# memory and computation complexity is O(buckets x indices.size), that's absolutely terrible.
indices_new_axis = tf.range(buckets, dtype=tf.int64)
indices = tf.stack([tf.cast(indices, tf.int64), indices_new_axis], axis=-1)
sparse_repr = tf.SparseTensor(indices, values, dense_shape=[buckets, indices.shape[0]])
dense_repr = tf.sparse.to_dense(sparse_repr)
result = tf.reduce_sum(dense_repr, axis=1)

print(result)
expected_result_dense = [1., 1.1, 0., 2., 0., .1, 0., 0.]
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(expected_result_dense, result.numpy())
# the same with sparse representation would also be good:
expected_indices_sparse = [0, 1, 3, 5]
expected_values_sparse = [1., 1.1, 2., .1]
```

Some technical background to the problem:

I am trying out Hough transform for some analytical shapes with confidence voting (without strictly thresholding the gradient, but still most points from original image are eliminated). With version without weights, I just use `tf.bincount` on indices and that works perfectly, I wonder if I can do something similar here.

I am aware that in this specific case, I can avoid the problem altogether by accumulating results while iterating through each lit pixel in the original image (there will be no duplicates, so I can materialize votes as `buckets` sized dense tensors and add them to the accumulator), but that's way less efficient than what should be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One day later, I finally found the solution. It's... well... rather simple:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

buckets = 8
indices = tf.convert_to_tensor([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 5], tf.int32)
values = tf.convert_to_tensor([.5, .3, .2, .1, 1., 1., 1., .1], tf.float32)

result = tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum(values, indices, buckets)
print(result)

expected_result_dense = [1., 1.1, 0., 2., 0., .1, 0., 0.]
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(expected_result_dense, result.numpy())
```

Turns out that there is already a function in TF 2.6 (and has been in TF for a while) that does exactly that. I was unable to find it since I was searching around `tf.bincount`, which is similar, but named completely differently.

On the way to the above solution I also found another that used `tf.sparse.reduce_sum()` (this required to change the data into a SparseTensor before), but above was much faster.